# Want to make a schema for a timetable in mongodb/mongoose for my project and how to model it with the user

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Now the problem is which data modeling should I use I am confused about embedding or referencing.
My project is about that a faculty can login and each faculty will have its own Time-Table and time-table is looking like this : [It is time-table of the faculty now how do I make its schema and how should i model it with the faculty like with embedding or referencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqLdo.png).
Anyone's help is Appericiated.